# Constructing object array using dynamic keys in react/Javscript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to contrcut the object based on response coming from API.

my key is assigned `this.RootKeyValue` and my response is assigned to `this.keyResponse`

`this.RootKeyValue` is the key of parent of first object .

In  second object based on the DynamicKey value need to create the key and values .

```js
this.RootKeyValue = "AccountDetails";
          
this.keyResponse = 
[ 
    {ICICI: 2,DynamicKey: "ICICI"},
    {SBI: 1.25,DynamicKey: "SBI"}
    {HDFC: 1.75,DynamicKey: "HDFC"}
]
```

how to construct the object like below using above key and response.
Expected result :

```js
{ 
   AccountDetails : 
    { ICICI :2 , SBI: 1.25,HDFC: 1.75 } 
}
```

I am new to react please suggest how to construct object using the dynamic key values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You build a dynamic object using square bracket notation

```
const obj = { ["SomeDynamicKey"]: someValue }
```

So in your case you can use `reduce` to build the object from your array:

```js
this.RootKeyValue = "AccountDetails";
          
this.keyResponse = 
[ 
    {ICICI: 2,DynamicKey: "ICICI"},
    {SBI: 1.25,DynamicKey: "SBI"},
    {HDFC: 1.75,DynamicKey: "HDFC"}
]   

const result = {
  [this.RootKeyValue] : this.keyResponse.reduce( (acc,item) => ({
    ...acc, 
    [item.DynamicKey]: item[item.DynamicKey]})
  ,{})
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: While `this.RootKeyValue`  is hardcoded, the above block uses too many computed values. also reduce is a overkill for this scenario as there are no complicated computation on a single item.

Comment: @PrakashS what are you talking about? This gives exactly the result the OP asked for, with just the right amount of dynamic values. WHatever do you mean by "overkill"? `reduce` is undoubtably the right tool for this job as its turning an array into a single object which is _exactly_ what reduce does!

Answer (score 0):

You can use square brackets to handle this very easily, e.g.

```js
const key = 'DYNAMIC_KEY';
const obj = { [key]: 'value' };
```

```js
const RootKeyValue = "AccountDetails";
const keyResponse = [ 
    { ICICI: 2,DynamicKey: "ICICI" },
    { SBI: 1.25,DynamicKey: "SBI" },
    { HDFC: 1.75,DynamicKey: "HDFC" }
];

const newData = { [RootKeyValue]: {} };
keyResponse.forEach(item => {
  newData[RootKeyValue][item.DynamicKey] = item[item.DynamicKey];
})

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the give array already has the dynamic keys and associate value in same object , you can create your desired object very easily like this.

```js
let given =   [ 
    {ICICI: 2,DynamicKey: "ICICI"},
    {SBI: 1.25,DynamicKey: "SBI"},
    {HDFC: 1.75,DynamicKey: "HDFC"}
] , AccountDetails = {};


given.forEach(item => {
  AccountDetails[item.DynamicKey] = item[item.DynamicKey] ? item[item.DynamicKey] : ''; 
})

console.log(AccountDetails);
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).